# How to use the new URLConnection class for HTTPClient deprecated class

Tags: android, http, url, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I am trying to use a class in my application. Till now it was working with HTTPClient class. But now HTTpClient class is deprecated, I need to Use URLConnection class. I want to replace the following piece of code, but I am not getting how to do that. Can anyone please let me know. how to do that below is my current code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(in);
```

How can I replace the above piece of code with URLConnection class from HTTPClient class?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for POST:

```
private void sendPost() throws Exception {

    String url = "your_url";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");


    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());

}
```

For more details, go through [How to send HTTP request GET/POST in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/).

For all deprecated classes look at the JavaDoc, it will hint at which class to use to replace the old code. Example:

```
...
*
* @deprecated (4.3) use {@link HttpClientBuilder}.  <----- THE HINT IS HERE !
*/
@ThreadSafe
@Deprecated
public class DefaultHttpClient extends AbstractHttpClient {
```

Therefore, I will suggest using

```
HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

As the `build()` method returns a `CloseableHttpClient` which is-a `AutoClosable`, you can place the declaration in a try-with-resources statement (Java 7+):

```
try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()){

// use httpClient (no need to close it explicitly)

} catch (IOException e) {

// handle

}
```

Hope it helps!