# java.net.httpurlconnection just wont work

Tags: java, android, http

I'm trying to make a simple http request in my android app.

`((HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://omg-a-site.org").openConnection()).getResponseCode();`

I tried using java.net.URL.getInputStream and java.net.URLConnection.getInputStream, but it just wont work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please give more details explaining what happens.  Do you get an exception?  Something else.  Note that the snippet in your question is not going to outpt anything if it succeeds.  You are not printing or displaying the response code ...

Comment: Follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30296238/how-to-use-the-new-urlconnection-class-for-httpclient-deprecated-class

Comment: please Post what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Your code *is* doing something.
Here is a try-catch with your code inside the "try" block. If any IOExceptions occur, the catch block will print out whatever is in the exception text.

```
try {
    ((HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://omg-a-site.org").openConnection()).getResponseCode();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

That code will produce the output below,
which looks reasonable – it cannot find a host named "omg-a-site.org":

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: omg-a-site.org
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:567)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:299)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:174)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:498)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:603)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:266)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:380)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:189)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:175)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1665)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:529)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:308)
    at a68.main(a68.java:8)
```

Comment: tried doing it... it produced the error:

`couldn't find method java.net.URL.<init> (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/net/URLConnection;`

I'm modding an app and just added this to the smali files..

`new-instance v0, Ljava/net/URL;
const-string v1, "http://example.com"
invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Ljava/net/URL;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/net/URLConnection;`

Comment: You'll need to update the original question to provide more detail about what you're doing, the code you wrote, how you're running it, etc.